# How to write multiple lines of Reddit data (using praw) to csv/txt file?

Tags: python, file, reddit, praw

I have fetched Reddit data to Python and aiming to write that to csv/txt file. The problem is that I'm only able to write one out of 100 lines to the file. The rest won't get written to the file for some reason.

I'm very amateur with Python and would appreciate a lot if someone can help with what I'm doing wrong. Many thanks!

Code:

```
import praw

myreddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xxxxx', client_secret='xxxxxx',
                       user_agent='Testing app')

newposts = myreddit.subreddit('Bitcoin').new(limit=100) #connection to 100 newest subreddits
for post in newposts:
    data = ('ID: {}, Date_utc: {}, Upvotes: {}, Number of comments: {}, Subthread name: {}'.format(post,
                                                                                                 post.created_utc,
                                                                                                 post.ups,
                                                                                                 post.num_comments,
                                                                                                 post.title)) #fetch following data: post ID, time, up votes, amt of comments, the titel of the subreddit
    with open('C:\\testRedditFetch.csv','w') as f: #open the file
         f.write(data) #write the file
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You're writing to a csv each time, this overwrites the current data, you can change the 'w' to 'a' which is append, that way your data will be appended and not overwritten.

```
import praw
import csv

myreddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='xxxxx', client_secret='xxxxxx',
                       user_agent='Testing app')

newposts = myreddit.subreddit('Bitcoin').new(limit=100) #connection to 100 newest subreddits
with open('C:\\testRedditFetch.csv','a') as f:
    headers = ['ID', 'Date_utc', 'Upvotes', 'Number of Comments', 'Subthread name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers, extrasaction='ignore', dialect='excel')
    writer.writeheader()
    for post in newposts:
        data = {'ID: {}, Date_utc: {}, Upvotes: {}, Number of comments: {}, Subthread name: {}'.format(post,
                                                                                                     post.created_utc,
                                                                                                     post.ups,
                                                                                                     post.num_comments,
                                                                                                     post.title)} #fetch following data: post ID, time, up votes, amt of comments, the titel of the subreddit
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Samt94! Very helpful

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, could you mark the answer as the solution please.